# Shortcut button to open userform in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with various worksheets. Each sheet has a  button to open a userform which i used to input data in the respective sheet. E.g. button 1 in "sheet1" to open userform1 to input data in sheet1. Button 2 in "sheet2" to open userform2 to input data in sheet2 and so on.

I wanted to create shortcut buttons for each button 1,2 in the main sheet to directly open respective userform i wanted.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that the buttons are form controls and you rename their caption "Form1", "Form2" and so on ..
The first sheet name is "Main" >> so try this code that will copy your buttons to the Main sheet

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim sh          As Worksheet
Dim shp         As Shape
Dim rw          As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
rw = 5

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> ws.Name Then
            sh.Activate
            For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Or shp.Type = msoFormControl Then
                    If Left(shp.AlternativeText, 4) = "Form" Then
                        shp.Copy
                        Application.Goto Sheets("Main").Range("G" & rw)
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        rw = rw + 2
                    End If
                End If
            Next shp
        End If
    Next sh
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```